# get numeric padding values from tensorflow

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a Tensorflow GraphDef :
https://github.com/gauravgupta22/tensorflow-caffe/blob/master/lenet.pbtxt

I am interested in calculating the real numeric padding values that are used internally by tensorflow (instead of 'SAME' or 'VALID')

Is there any built-in method or some function or any way to get these?

I found a link which explains how the values are calculated : https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html

For the 'VALID' padding, the padding values are always zero.

For the 'SAME' padding

```
out_height = ceil(float(in_height) / float(strides[1]))
out_width  = ceil(float(in_width) / float(strides[2]))

pad_along_height = ((out_height - 1) * strides[1] +
                filter_height - in_height)
pad_along_width = ((out_width - 1) * strides[2] +
                   filter_width - in_width)
pad_top = pad_along_height / 2
pad_left = pad_along_width / 2
```

To use this calculations, it requires me to calculate input shapes of tensors for the operations involved.

```
# code to import a graph and print input/output tensor shapes of its operations

import tensorflow as tf
from google.protobuf import text_format
from tensorflow.core.framework import graph_pb2

graph_def = graph_pb2.GraphDef()
with open('lenet.pbtxt', "rb") as f:
    text_format.Merge(f.read(), graph_def)

tf.import_graph_def(graph_def,name='')

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
for i in graph.get_operations():
    print i.name
    print 'INPUTS ',
    for j in i.inputs:
        print j.get_shape(),
    print '\nOUTPUTS ',
    for j in i.outputs:
        print j.get_shape(),
    print
```

But I get some shapes like:

```
INPUTS  (?, ?) <unknown> 
OUTPUTS  (?, ?)
```

Clearly these cannot be used.
**So how can i get complete tensor shapes or indirectly how do i calculate the numeric padding values?**

Please help

**EDIT**
I made a tensorflow model and exported it to graphdef using `tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()`
Now if i import this graphdef again, i get tensors with `<unknown>` shapes. I lose the info of inferred tensor shapes!!

On the other hand, if i export my model using `tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(add_shapes=True)`and import this again, I am able to tensor shapes!

But i want my code to work in general with any graphdef
**Is `tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()` not the perfect way to save a graph or there is some other way i could get inferred tensor shapes out of it?**

**EDIT**
I submitted an issue
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3903

Comment: In general tensors in a Tensorflow graph may have dynamic shapes. Shape inference is best-effort; there is no guarantee that get_shape() will return a numeric shape for a particular graph. Can you say a little more about what you're trying to do? Perhaps there is another way to solve your problem.

Comment: @PeterHawkins I was trying to convert a Tensorflow model (graph_def) into a JSON object. I could easily find all the parameters but padding seems to be a problem. Tensorflow uses ('SAME'/'VALID') but i need numeric values

Comment: `as_graph_def` was first created before static shape inference, so it defaults to `add_shapes=False` for backward compatibility. However, the newer `export_meta_graph` calls `as_graph_def` with `add_shapes=True`.

Comment: This is a good question, especially if the stride is not the default 1.